# What is the usefulness of NMTOKEN and NMTOKENS types?

Tags: xsd

1. The value of `NMTOKEN` follows the same rules as XML name, except with `NMTOKEN` any of the allowed characters can be the first character. Unlike XML `string` type, `NMTOKEN` values can’t contain any whitespace. Still I fail to see its usefulness.

   So when and why would we use `NMTOKEN` type instead of a `string` type?
2. `NMTOKENS` enables us to specify several `NMTOKEN` values (separated by whitespace) in a single string. This type makes even less sense, since it also allows a value to contain whitespace characters, which essentially means that both `NMTOKENS` type and `string` type can hold exactly the same values.

   So when is this type useful?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`NMTOKEN` and `NMTOKENS` exist in XML Schema only for compatibility with DTDs, the predecessor of XML Schema, which had those as attributes types. DTD has few other types so those don't stand out as redundant there.

So use `NMTOKEN` and `NMTOKENS` when you're converting a DTD to an XML Schema.

Addendum: Those and other all caps types fall into the same category. They are marked in the XML Schema Rec with the text, "For compatibility NMTOKEN should be used only on attributes."

If they exactly fit your needs, it might be easiest to use just them, but the XML Schema way is to derive from `xs:string` or `xs:token` and constrain as needed with a `pattern` facet. Or, more commonly in my experience, use `xs:string` or `xs:token` as-is and call it close enough.

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner. If NMTOKEN and NMTOKENS exist only for compatibility with DTDs, then what types should XML Schema use instead of the NMTOKEN and NMTOKENS when DTD compatibility is not an issue?

Comment: I've added to the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Couldn't you use **xs:list** for **xs:NMTOKENS** to represent a space separated list. Your xs:list itemType could then have the required restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I think, NMTOKEN are useful for defining values, that respresent HTML5 compatible id values or  HTML class names. Contrary to previous HTML versions, HTML5 permits ids that begin with a digit.

NMTOKENS are useful for (comma separated) lists of HTML5 ids or HTML classes.

Answer (score -1):

NMTOKENS is an very useful data type, they allow alphabets, digits and '.', ':' and '-' special characters [Refer](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re84.html).

In my experience they are very handy to define multi-value attributes, which can have the above characters. In XML the other method of defining multi-valued attributes would involve restricting a string type with regex, which is more involving (flexible however) than using the NMTOKENS type.

Of course, a different data modelling approach could be taken with elements but NMTOKENS is the shortest mechanism to declare a multi-values attribute.